# Proper collision in SFML (C++)

Tags: c++, collision, sfml

So, I had a test going on to see how collision operates in SFML. I have made this snippet of code:

```
if (floor.getGlobalBounds().intersects(SuperMario.getGlobalBounds())) // Floor
    {
        SuperMario.setPosition(SuperMario.getPosition().x, floor.getPosition().y - SuperMario.getOrigin().y);
        IsTouching = true;
    }
```

As the code suggests, Mario will change his position when he touches the floor object and will teleport above the floor.

However, this has the following side-effect, illustrated by the pictures below.
[image: 2nd image]

[image]

Note that the "green box" is the floor object I mentioned earlier. Also, ignore the word "left" in picture 1, I mean "right".

Of course, this behaviour is  intended (i.e. is not a bug), but it is unwanted.

So my question is: How can I eliminate this "side-effect"? I mean, how can I modify my code, so Mario will not teleport above the floor, when he touches its sides(making platforming work like a proper platforming)? I want Mario to be stopped by the box, not to be teleported.

**UPDATE: So now, I have this:**

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= solidObjects.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (solidObjects[i].getGlobalBounds().intersects(SuperMario.getGlobalBounds()))
        {
            if (SuperMario.getPosition().x - solidObjects[i].getPosition().x  < SuperMario.getPosition().y - solidObjects[i].getPosition().y)
            {
                SuperMario.setPosition(solidObjects[i].getPosition().x - SuperMario.getOrigin().x, SuperMario.getPosition().y);
                IsTouching = false;
            }
            else if (SuperMario.getPosition().y - solidObjects[i].getPosition().y < SuperMario.getPosition().x - solidObjects[i].getPosition().x)
            {
                SuperMario.setPosition(SuperMario.getPosition().x, solidObjects[i].getPosition().y - SuperMario.getOrigin().y);
                IsTouching = true;
            }
            else if (SuperMario.getPosition().x - solidObjects[i].getTextureRect().width < SuperMario.getPosition().y - solidObjects[i].getPosition().y)
            {
                SuperMario.setPosition(solidObjects[i].getTextureRect().width + SuperMario.getOrigin().x, SuperMario.getPosition().y);
                IsTouching = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            IsTouching = false;
        }
    }
```

**However, there is one problem. When Mario touches the sides of the floor, he sticks on them meaning he is unable to move right.**

If I am not clear enough, please specify what i should add or clarify more.

Comment: What exactly is the behavior you'd like to avoid? The teleportation? Want to get stopped by the box?

Comment: Yes! I want exactly that!

Comment: By comparing x/y positions and width/height you can figure out if what direction would require the least amount of movement to get Mario outside the floor rect. That's the direction you want to move Mario.

Comment: @super However, what command can make mario stop moving? Do I implement the same `SuperMario.setPosition(SuperMario.getPosition().x, floor.getPosition().y - SuperMario.getOrigin().y);` snippet, but modified according to each axis?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Depending on how sophisticated collision detection you need, OBB vs OBB or SAT collision can be good things to read up on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels really weird, because you'd typically define solid areas rather than those the player can walk inside. You'll want your player to jump after all, rather than having them glued to the ground.

The rest is pretty straightforward:

- Iterate over all solid objects and determine whether the player and the solid rectangle overlap.
- If they do, determine which distance is smaller (x or y). This lets you determine which axis to move the player.
- Determine which direction the player leaves the solid area quicker, i.e. which direction to push the player.
- Push the player in the calculated direction and repeat the checks.

Depending on your map complexity this can become rather complex, so you'll most likely want some sorting/spatialisation to reduce the number of comparisons (e.g. skip checking impossible/far away shapes).

Comment: @ToadTheMushroomCoder The way you defined the function above he should be glued, but this might depend on how you implemented jumping.

Comment: I have a last question. How do I iterate solid objects exactly?

Comment: @ToadTheMushroomCoder You'd have them in some container like a `std::vector`.

Comment: Okay, so I have done all the collision which works properly (my code is in the update section of my question), but Mario will stick to the sides of the floor when touching them. Why is this?

Comment: @ToadTheMushroomCoder Not 100% sure what you mean, but the basic idea would be to do the X checks a bit above the Y checks to avoid them triggering on the ground level (i.e. on tiles or objects you're standing on). If that's not what you mean, I'd suggest you open a new question and – if possible – post a short video clip showing your problem.

Comment: I got over the issue. Apparently, the width of my character was bigger than his origin, thus making the character collide infinetely with the floor when he touches the left side of the floor, even after he changed position. That made him unable to move. Thanks for your help :)